# How do I target others so I can heal them?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can you target an ally to perform a heal on them instead of yourself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Being able to heal others depends on what spell you're using:

- You can't heal others with *Healing*, *Fast Healing*, or *Close Wounds*: they're self-cast only.
- You can get *Healing Hands* and *Heal Other*, which let you heal most targets (including followers). They work just like offensive spells: point and shoot.
- You can also get *Grand Healing*, which is an area-of-effect heal. This heals *everyone* in the area of effect, though: including enemies. This is not targeted: it heals everyone within range of the caster.

Comment: And just to add, there are several places to buy the healing spells. You can talk to the court wizard in whiterun for example. He has a spell (healing hands I believe) that will heal your target.